# Mouse wheel event has jittery zoom/scale in JointJS

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

I'm trying to implement a zoom function using the mouse wheel in JointJS.  The intent is to use the paper.scale() function and use the mouse coordinates for the ox & oy options.  However, when I move the mouse it gets a jittery effect in the translation.

There are several zoom implementations available with a quick google search, but they all seem to suffer from the same issue.

Here is my code based on my best iterpretation of the JointJS documentation.  I'm assuming the x & y are already translated to paperspace.

```
paper.on('blank:mousewheel', function(evt, x, y, delta) {


    var normalizedDelta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (delta))) / 50;
    var newScale = paper.scale().sx + normalizedDelta; // the current paper scale changed by delta

  if (newScale > 0.4 && newScale < 2) {
    paper.translate(0, 0); // setOrigin is deprecated, replaced by translate
    paper.scale(newScale, newScale, x, y);
  }
})
```

Here is some zoom code I found by googling.  It has the same effect.  I've messed around with using offsetX/offsetY, local coordinates, & paper coordinates, all without luck.

```
paper.$el.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheel);

function onMouseWheel(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e = e.originalEvent;

  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail))) / 50;
  var offsetX = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $(this).offset().left); // offsetX is not defined in FF
  var offsetY = (e.offsetY || e.clientY - $(this).offset().top); // offsetY is not defined in FF
  var localPoint = offsetToLocalPoint(offsetX, offsetY);

  var newScale = V(paper.viewport).scale().sx + delta; // the current paper scale changed by delta

  if (newScale > 0.4 && newScale < 2) {
    paper.translate(0, 0);  // setOrigin is deprecated, replaced by translate
    paper.scale(newScale, newScale, localPoint.x, localPoint.y); //p.x, p.y);
  }
}

function offsetToLocalPoint(x, y) {
  var svgPoint = paper.svg.createSVGPoint();

  svgPoint.x = x;
  svgPoint.y = y;

  // Transform point into the viewport coordinate system.
  var pointTransformed = svgPoint.matrixTransform(paper.viewport.getCTM().inverse());
  return pointTransformed;
}
```

I'm expecting this to zoom in on whatever point the mouse is located.  The scaling works quite nicely when the ox & oy are set to zero.  When I attempt to use the mouse coordinates for the ox & oy options, it appears to work.  However, when I move the mouse around it gets a jittery translation effect.  It seems like the ox & oy coordinates are delayed by one event.

Here is my attempt [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blbeggs/fx6tyjvr/).

Here is the attempt I found via google [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blbeggs/o32p1xg6/)

Comment: This is a bit old, but are you referring to the part where when you zoom in/out you end up scrolling first, and then the actual zoom kicks in?

Answer (score 2):

I finally did it:

```
paper.on("blank:mousewheel", function(evt, x, y, delta) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const oldscale = paper.scale().sx;
  const newscale = oldscale + 0.2 * delta * oldscale

  if (newscale>0.2 && newscale<5) {
    paper.scale(newscale, newscale, 0, 0);
    paper.translate(-x*newscale+evt.offsetX,-y*newscale+evt.offsetY);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nj5cqusg/1/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how you get smooth zoom in/out even if the mouse is on an element or text or whatever:

```
$('#paper').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let scale = paper.scale().sx;

    // Get the current translation
    let translate = paper.translate();

    // Get mouse position relative to the document
    let mouseX = evt.pageX;
    let mouseY = evt.pageY;

    // Convert to position relative to the paper
    let x = (mouseX - $(this).offset().left - translate.tx) / scale;
    let y = (mouseY - $(this).offset().top - translate.ty) / scale;

    const offsetX = Math.trunc(evt.clientX - $(this).offset().left);
    const offsetY = Math.trunc(evt.clientY - $(this).offset().top);

    const oldScale = paper.scale().sx;
    const newScale = oldScale - 0.05 * (evt.detail / 3) * oldScale;

    if (newScale > 0.1 && newScale < 1) {
        paper.scale(newScale, newScale, 0, 0);
        paper.translate(-x * newScale + offsetX, -y * newScale + offsetY);
    }
});
```